# Python call class property from same classmethod

Tags: python-3.x, oop, kubernetes

I have class method **wait_for_operation** from which i want to call the the class property and generate a new client that i want to use with the class method.

```
def get_new_bearer_token():
    return "new_token"

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, json):
        self.json = json

    @property
    def client(self):
        k8_loader = kube_config.KubeConfigLoader(self.json)
        call_config = type.__call__(Configuration)
        k8_loader.load_and_set(call_config)
        Configuration.set_default(call_config)
        return client

    @classmethod
    def wait_for_operation(self, kube_config, cloud):
        while True:
                if cloud == "AWS":
                    kube_config['users'][0]['user']['token'] = get_new_bearer_token()
                    self.json = kube_config
                    #call class property to generate a new client with token and use it


if __name__ == '__main__':
    kube_config = {}
    my_client = MyClass(json=kube_config)
    my_client.client.CoreV1Api().list_namespace(watch=False)
    result = MyClass.wait_for_operation(kube_config=kube_config,cloud='AWS')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a very bad idea to use properties that change state or have side effects. Properties are meant to represent a view of instance data, and that's why we don't really say "to call a property", but to "get or set a property".

My advice - remove `@property` decorator and make `client` into a ordinary method. Give it a better name, like `generate_new_client`. Then call it like any other method - `self.generate_new_client()`.